# Arg Programa - Login con JWT

Tags: netbeans, login, jwt

En mi package ...Security, en la class MainSecurity.java (según youtube MGB video Parte 15 Login con JWT) utiliza el "extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" que a mí me aparece tachado, también en el import que sigue. Y no realiza, aunque muestra, los dos imports siguiente (SessionCreationPolicy; y BCryptPasswordEncoder;

Podrían guiarme en cómo mejorar mi pregunta y cómo resolver el problema. La versión de NetBeans que utilizo es 19.
Gracias.

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola. La pregunta debe ser autocontenida ("youtube xyz sección x" no cumple con esa idea). El código que estás escribiendo debe estar en la pregunta a forma de  [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No es claro qué quieres decir con que no realiza imports aunque sí los muestra. Así pues, no es claro _cuál es el problema_. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.